# How to launch Linux TortoiseHg GUI

Tags: ubuntu, tortoisehg

On Ubuntu 11.04, I've installed 'TortoiseHg' and 'TortoiseHg-Nautilus' through Software Update Center, but still have no idea how to launch the TortoiseHg GUI. I've tried to use command 'hgtk' in terminal but it only prints out help information. Also, right click on the folder in Nautilus (not sure if it's Nautilus, I click the 'Home Folder' button on the launch bar) doesn't see a TortoiseHg entry, like the one in Windows. How do I use Linux TortoiseHg GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 11.10 with Unity desktop. After klicking at the "start menu button" (sorry for that word, I don't know its real name) I enter "TortoiseHg" and then klick at the only one icon that appears.

I agree, the intergration into Nautilus isn't as good as it is on Windows, but THg is running well.

Answer (score 0):

`tortoisehg: Command not found.`

Run at terminal

`thg`